# How to make a result for com.huawei.hmf.tasks?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-hmf-tasks

In `com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks` there is a `forResult` method which returns a specific result for the task, how related this method to Huawei's tasks?

```kotlin
// return a null result task
Task<?> methodCallTask;
methodCallTask = Tasks.forResult(null);
```

Comment: What do you want to return `OnSuccessTask`, `OnFailureTask`, `isCompleteTask`?

Comment: There is no method called `forResult` in Huawei Tasks.  `forResult` is only in Google Mobile Services Tasks which is not related to Huawei Mobile Services Tasks completely.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei have `com.huawei.hmf.tasks.Tasks.fromResult(null);`Similar to google.

Answer (score 0):

The HMS Tasks API reference doc is located at [Common-Task (huawei.com)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/task_tresult-0000001050121148).

The GMS Tasks API reference doc is located at [Tasks  |  Google Play services  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks).

Compared both GMS Tasks APIs and HMS Tasks APIs. It looks like they don't have the exact same API of GMS `Tasks.forResult()`. The closely related HMS Tasks API might be `getResult()`. [Common-Task (huawei.com)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/task_tresult-0000001050121148#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050121148__section1531714283207)